# Unable to change File Permission on Linux with root user

Tags: linux, sudo, chmod

I ran this command logged as root user
    #chmod 777 
and got this message : Read Only file system error
I also ran this command as root user
    #sudo chmod 777 
and got this message: Bus Error

Please help how can i change file permission on this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message indicates that you are working on a read-only file system, so you cannot modify access attributes of files within that file system. You can check this by executing the `mount` command.